# Server-Syncing DB App, Questions on Primary Keys, Multiple Tables, and Saving Storage Space

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, primary-key

I plan on making an app that can optionally store data-entries on a mysql central server (cloud) and use that server as a way to backup your data-entries or to sync data-entries between different devices.

Right now my very rough table layouts look something like this:

---

### Server's USER Table

- USER_ID (INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT)
- LAST_UPDATE - timestamp with last time any data-entry was updated
- EMAIL
- PASSWORD - salted and hashed

### Server's Data Entry Table

- SERVER_ENTRY_ID  (INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT)  - would be unique across all devices
- USER_ID          (INT)   - from server's user table
- LAST_UPDATE          - timestamp with last time this data-entry was updated
- Columns_For_Actual_Data...

### Client-App Data Entry Table

- ROW_ID               (INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT)  - used for local app DB operations only, not shared
- SERVER_ENTRY_ID  (INT) - this is the unique server data-entry ID retrieved from server when added to server
- LAST_UPDATE          - timestamp with last time this data-entry was locally in app
- Columns_For_Actual_Data...

---

### Questions

My questions are actually not about the syncing logic. I want to plan ahead as much as possible to avoid potential problems if I get a lot of users and data entries.

1. Is it ok to use an INT autoincrement primary key (PK) for useful info like a UserID or Data-Entry-ID? I've heard that is not good practice, but i've also seen examples where the PK is used for useful info. Is the concern that it would be hard to migrate the rows into different tables or databases if I needed to do so? The SERVER_ENTRY_ID would be the same on the server as it is on all devices that sync with that server. An alternative idea is to use UUIDs for SERVER_ENTRY_ID but they are not autoincremented so I think it would be slower to search and also take up much more DB space (16 byte blob).
2. If data-entry tables might get extremely large on the server is it a good idea to make multiple data-entry tables instead? For instance user_id 0-9999 could use Table1, user_id 10000 - 19999 would use Table2, etc. Also, keeping a user's data all in one table would make retrieving all data for a single user faster than separate tables.
3. Let's say I have a data-entry table with 5 INT columns and 3 DOUBLE columns that are used to store actual data. Lets also say that these 8 columns are only ever needed together and are never searched for in a WHERE clause with MYSQL queries. Let's also say that these 8 columns often have 0's as values. Since MySql uses the same amount of storage space to store an INT of 0 and 2,147,483,647, would it be best space-wise to instead store these 8 columns as a byte blob using a storage schema kind of like https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#varint?

Comment: Which DBMS are you actually using? mysql <> sql server.

Comment: I'm using mysql. The sql-server tag was a mistake.

Comment: For **1**, natural vs surrogate keys have advantages and disadvantages, read http://www.agiledata.org/essays/keys.html.  I like surrogate keys since they have no business logic attached, and makes it easier to change the logic without having to reindex.  But read up on it, chose according to your requirements.

Comment: For **2**, how large is very large?  Tables can get darn big before performance is impacted significantly, and splitting them comes at a price in code.  For **3** in theory you should split them to maintain normal forms.  But compromises exist for implementation simplicity.  Remember that changing that is more complicated than adding a new column (especially if you need to change the order the values are stored in).  You cannot search on the values, nor can you index them.  But the compromise *might* be ok for your case.

Comment: Nic3500 - Thanks for help. For 2, this is all extreme precaution and unlikely.. but let's say I end up having 50 million entries in one table. In general where is the cut-off of an acceptable number of rows per table in your opinion? I know it depends on hardware, queries, programming, etc, but in general. I also want a table that is easily backed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No cutoff in the number of rows in one table. As a table gets bigger, more and more issues arise. A hundred-row table works fine without normalization and indexes; a billion row table needs both, plus shrinking datatypes. Etc, etc.  (In one survey, 50M rows was about the 96th percentile.  I have seen over a billion rows in a single table.)

UUIDs suck performance for huge tables; try to avoid them.  (Yes, packing them into `BINARY(16)` is better than `VARCHAR(36)`.

2/3 of *my* tables do not use `AUTO_INCREMENT`; instead, they have a 'natural' PK.  So, clearly, I say "it depends" when it comes to PKs.  UserID is likely to best be done with `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` or `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED`, depending on whether you expect no more than 64K or 16M users.  Rarely does one need `INT`, much less `BIGINT`.  (Their sizes are 2,3,4,8 bytes, respectively.)

A drawback of non-`AUTO_INCREMENT` PK is that a copy of the PK is concatenated to each secondary key, thereby adding to their bulk.  However, roughly speaking:

- Big PK, but no secondary keys:  Fine
- Big PK and *one* secondary key:  Takes about same disk space with or without AI.
- Big PK and multiple secondary keys:  AI is beginning to shine (space-wise).

Do *not* split a big table across multiple smaller tables.  The hassle is huge, the benefit is minuscule.  Even `PARTITIONing` is unlikely to provide *any* benefit.

"Normalizing" big-ish columns with repeated values is *usually* a good idea.  (Saves space, yet `JOIN` to put things back together is not bad.)

50M rows with those 8 columns might add up to about 4GB.  This is not terribly big.  It does not warrant playing `BLOB` games (unless the app code would *really* prefer it that way.)  Meanwhile, consider smaller integer types than the 4-byte `INT`; consider `UNSIGNED`; consider `FLOAT` versus `DOUBLE.

There is no equivalent of 'varint' in MySQL.

Comments on http://www.agiledata.org/essays/keys.html :

- A 'key' does not necessarily *uniquely* identify a row.  Ditto for 'secondary key'.  The keyword `UNIQUE` is needed.
- In MySQL, the `PRIMARY KEY` is special in that it uniquely identifies the row and is "clustered" with the data.
- In MySQL, it is almost always preferred to use `VARCHAR` instead of `CHAR`.
- In MySQL, `AUTO_INCREMENT` is usually the preferred technique for 'surrogate' keys.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll probably go with auto-incremented unsigned MediumInt for UserID in the User table and auto-incremented unsigned int for one large data-entry table. I won't mess with making blobs for the other data.